# How to fix / debug errors (invalid arrayify value) when deploying a solidity contract in Remix

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

### Problem

I am trying to deploy a smart contract via [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/). Unfortunately, it fails with a very unhelpful error message.

### Error Message

> creation of MyContract errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.5.0)

### Code

Here is the constructor the `contract` uses:

```
struct RRSet {
    uint32 inception;
    uint32 expiration;
    bytes20 hash;
}

constructor(bytes memory _anchors) {
    // Insert the 'trust anchors' - the key hashes that start the chain
    // of trust for all other records.
    anchors = _anchors;
    rrsets[keccak256(hex"00")][DNSTYPE_DS] = RRSet({
        inception: uint32(0),
        expiration: uint32(3767581600), // May 22 2089 - the latest date we can encode as of writing this
        hash: bytes20(keccak256(anchors))
    });
    emit RRSetUpdated(hex"00", anchors);
}
```

### Some thoughts

My contract uses `is` to inherit from an abstract contract as wells as from a regular contract. Is there a way to see where to error or originates from or is there a possiblity to debug it?

Comment: It seems like there's a constructor requiring some parameters but you're passing empty or incorrectly formatted values. Can you share the constructor code and what you're passing to it?

Comment: I updated the code with the constructor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constructor takes a byte array as an argument.

When you pass an empty value, it results in the error message mentioned in your question. It's because you're effectively passing "no value" - not "empty byte array".

[image: empty value]

> *creation of MyContract errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.5.0)*

If you want to pass an empty byte array, you need to use the `[]` or `0x` expression (both options work):

[image: empty array]

[image: empty array]